# Create Contact Exchange 365 Org - Powershell and Graph

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

I am trying to create a contact object in our Exchange Online environment. I am connected with the Directory.ReadWrite.All scope.

I can retrieve any created contacts, but when I run the create contact it gives me an error:

```
new-mgcontact -DisplayName "Peter Parker" -mail "peter.parker@spiderverse.com" -MailnickName -"peter.parker"
```

I just an error saying: One or more errors occured. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.directorymanagement/new-mgcontact?view=graph-powershell-1.0#-onpremisesprovisioningerrors

Answer (score 0):

In the production v1.0 endpoint there has never been any support for creating/modifying or deleting OrgContacts as per https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-metadata/issues/244 they are read-only and the reason you see the cmdlet is a bug . You may have better luck in the beta namespace but that seems to be undocumented or possibly a private preview the other commentor is using.

If you want a supported method you still have to use the exov3 cmdlet https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-mailcontact?view=exchange-ps